# Get date from filename to change date in Meta Info of mp4 file with Exiftool

Tags: windows, command-line, exiftool

I'm trying to change the date of when my movies were taken. The information got lost as I changed the format (for a neccessarry reason). I googled and want to try with exiftool.

Example Filename: PXL_20220113_173346874.mp4

First code I tried:

```
exiftool.exe "-DateTimeOriginal<${filename;s/PXL_(\d{8})_*.mp4}" -d "%Y%m%d"
```

Instead of * I tried different things but always got the error: No file specified.

Reading further I realised I might have to use CreateDate. So next code:

```
exiftool.exe -api QuickTimeUTC "-CreateDate<Filename" PXL_20220525_132344600.mp4
```

That worked but only for one specific file. How can I change the code that it works for all files in the folder? I don't see it....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass exiftool any number of individual files and directory paths, limited only by the command line length.

For example

```
exiftool.exe -api QuickTimeUTC "-CreateDate<Filename" /path/to/Directory1/ /path/to/Directory2/ /path/to/File1.mp4 /path/to/File2.mp4
```

will process all the files in Directory1 and Directory2 (but not in subdirectories, see below), as well as the individual files File1.mp4 and File2.mp4.

If you need to recurse into subdirectories, add the [`-r` (`-recurse`) option](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse).  If you need to limit processing to specific file types, such as MP4s, then add the [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension), i.e. using `-ext mp4 -ext mov` will only process MP4 and MOV files.  You cannot use an asterisk as a wildcard when recursing.  See [Exiftool Common Mistake #2](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M2)

This command creates backup files.  Add the [`-overwrite_original` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.

Comment: As I was in the correct directory I wrote PXL_* and -ext .mp4 instead of the path/to Stuff. That worked. Thank you! I don’t even know why that didn’t came to my mind.